# How do I reduce the effects of Boss Modifiers?

Tags: diablo-iii

As a melee character, I am often melted by plague, desecrator, and molten [Boss Modifiers](http://www.diablowiki.net/Boss_Modifiers), tearing through 24k HP. What can I do to delay my death? How severely will resistances assist, and what resistance should I pair with each Modifier? Is it worth equipping resistances before entering, say, an area with many molten enemies? What about the INT stat? How much do I need to equip (as a DEX character) before I start seeing results? What other skills and buffs apply here?

Comment: Having just read a lot of barb comments QQ in the blizzard forums, I don't think there is a good solution to this problem (and you didn't mention difficulty, but at 24k HP I am guessing Hell or Inferno)

Comment: I figured any answer's effect would just scale for difficulty

Comment: If you're a monk, you can be invulnerable for 4 seconds every 20 seconds.  It looks like barbs don't really have an equivalent, as they can only increase existing armor and resists, not become immune outright.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing to do would indeed be to stack resistances.

- Desceration damage is Physical.
- Plague damage is Poison.
- Molten damage is Fire.

I'd strongly suggest finding items with a decent amount of your Primary Stats, Vitality, and Resist All Elements for melee characters. If you find yourself having more trouble with one specific type you can always look for resistance armor on the AH for that specific stat. Resistances are a huge deal in the harder difficulties for melee characters, so I'd highly suggest stacking Resist All Elements items (Rapida had to start doing that on his Barbarian in order to survive certain effects on in Inferno).